# Ocultar algo HTML (Texto, Imagens)

Tags: html

Gostaria de saber se é possível ocultar uma imagem/video em um site HTML
mas a imagem/video permanecer ali, e caso clique na imagem/vídeo ele pode
ser reproduzido no player de imagem/video

Como se a imagem/vídeo estivesse ali, podendo ser clicado e executando atividades, mas estando ocultos

Comment: Porque você está interessado em fazer isso? Você tem o link de algum site que faça isso para dar como exemplo do que você quer? Talvez você possa simplesmente aplicar um `display: none;` no que quer ocultar e colocar no lugar um elemento com o qual possa interagir e usar para abrir a imagem/vídeo ocultado.

Comment: Amigo se o bagulho vai estar oculto como vc vai clicar nele??

Comment: @Douglas Quero fazer uma promoção no meu site, que é basicamente o cliente que achar a imagem ganha 5% de desconto no cupom da foto https://youtu.be/i7SgSaRuM5Q?t=94

Comment: Dependendo da forma como for implementado, pode ser bem fácil para um usuário um pouco mais avançado encontrar a imagem, se ele souber abrir o código fonte da página (Ctrl+U) ou as ferramentas de desenvolvedor (Ctrl+Shift+i). Mesmo assim, não seria simplesmente o caso de você colocar uma div invisível em algum lugar da página, que irá reagir quando o cursor passar sobre ela ou quando ela for clicada? A reação da div seria chamar um código javascript (ou ter um CSS `::before`) que faz aparecer o cupom. Seria isso?

Comment: Sim! isso mesmo como faz?

Comment: @Douglas Sim! isso mesmo como faz?

Comment: No link que você colocou no comentário, eu vi usarem `opacity: 0;` para deixar o elemento invisível. Testei numa sugestão de vídeo ao lado e o que aconteceu é que a sugestão "desapareceu" (pois ficou 100% transparente) mas continuou ocupando seu espaço, e ainda foi possível clicar nela (o cursor também muda ao passar sobre ela normalmente) e abrir o vídeo. Talvez essa seja a solução mais fácil para você: Coloque a imagem do cupom onde ela deve ficar na página, dê `opacity: 0;`, e faça-a ter `opacity: 1;` quando houver evento `hover` nela. Nem precisa do javascript.

Comment: camufle com hidden o video ou imagem e esconda o link em algum lugar ou diversos objetos para confundir, induzindo ao erro., use php assim o usuário não vai ver qual link correto

Comment: @Douglas Poderia me explicar melhor? Ou me enviar tudo já pronto!

Comment: Mano se vc quer fazer igual ao vídeo que vc citou no link o seu site vai tomar om punição do Google cedo ou tarde. Isso é prática de `black hat` e vc pode até ser banido dos resultados de busco do Google... fica a dica

Answer (score 1):

Aqui está uma solução bem simples, não é algo extraordinário. Basicamente, se utiliza do seletor `target` que irá aplicar um estilo ao clicar sobre o elemento, aplicando o `visibility: visible` no elemento.

"O problema" disso, é que é necessário referenciar uma tag `<a>`, apontando com o `href` para onde quer redirecionar, no caso o `id` do elemento que quer mostrar.

```css
.principal{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
#borda{
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
#promocao{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: context-menu;
}
#outros{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
#outros:target{
  text-align: center;
  visibility: visible;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="principal">
  <div id="borda">
    <a href="#outros">
      <div id="promocao"></div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div id="outros"> VOCÊ ACHOU O MEGA CUPOM DE DESCONTO </div>
</div>
```

Obs: deixei uma borda, para visualizar onde está o campo que é clicável.

Comment: legal, só uma dúvida: existe a possibilidade de, enquanto a página estiver sendo carregada, o cupom aparecer rapidamente (antes do `opacity: 0;` ser carregado) para depois desaparecer (quando o `opacity: 0;` for carregado)?

Comment: PERFEITO! Mas, eu gostaria que a pessoa desse um click no local!

Comment: @Douglas, segundo os meus conhecimentos, no CSS não. Nem ele, nem o `display` e nem o `visibility`. Já fiz o teste aplicando uma classe pelo JS, mais especificamente JQuery, e com ele apareceu a `div` antes de terminar de carregar e depois desapareceu.

Comment: @Douglas pelo que entendi você gostaria de piscar a div e depois ocultá-la, isso bem rapidamente, é isto? Se positivo, você precisa utilizar `keyframes` em CSS, um tópico que talvez ajude: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846224/css-animation-with-delay-and-opacity

Comment: +1, @TiagoBoeing na verdade eu perguntei isso porque, como se trata de esconder um cupom de desconto na página, provavelmente seria um comportamento indesejado se o cupom aparecesse durante o carregamento da página (ficaria fácil demais achá-lo). Pelo que entendi do intuito do `sdfw`, seria interessante ter certeza que o cupom só aparecerá quando o usuário passar o cursor sobre ele ou clicar nele, e nunca durante o carregamento da página.

Comment: Ah sim, neste caso a resposta do @sdfw é a melhor. Você pode ocultar o cursor de "mãozinha" do mouse, assim no computador fica mais difícil achar. Basta adicionar no css `cursor: none;`